# Programmatically get usage statistics for lists and items

Tags: 2013, development, site-usage

I understand it is possible to get usage data for the web and a site collection, however, is it possible to get detailed usage data for every list in a site and every item in those lists programmatically?

Comment: Do you mean the number of visits for each list item?